# Searching through an list

Tags: algorithm, chess, lookup-tables

I'm reading about AI and in the notes it is mentioned

> A lookup table in chess would have roughly 35^100 entries.

But what does this mean? Is there any way we could find out how long it would take the computer to search through and find it's entry? Would we assume thereis some order or that there is no order?

Comment: Why do you assume the lookup table is a list, which would have to be searched?

Comment: It's not so much a problem about time as it is about memory

Comment: Why speculate on the internal layout of an infeasible data structure? You might as well ask about how unicorns digest their food.

Comment: It's easy enough to estimate how long it would take to search a list of any size, assuming of course that the list could exist. Which, as others have pointed out, cannot. 35^100 works out to 2.55e+154. If we assume that you can search a billion items a second, it would take 2.55e+145 seconds, or about 8e+137 years to search the entire list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of atoms in the known universe is estimated to be around 10^80 which is much less than 35^100. With current technology, at least a few thousand atoms are required to store a single bit. I assume that each entry of your table would have multiple bits. You would need some really advanced technology to implement the memory of your computer.

So the answer is: With current technology it is not a matter of time, it is simply impossible.